# Binding const array to a grid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to Silverlight, so this might be a simple question to answer. I have a grid (not DataGrid from the toolkit), so that data displayed in it can be easily tabulated. I want to bind the grid to a string array that never changes, hence the number of rows and columns in the grid will not change either. I see that I cannot specify a template like I can for a ListBox (ListBox.ItemTemplate) and I don't want to define each row and column explicitly (with a TextBlock in each one of them) in XAML. And I also dont want to generate rows and columns dynamically in code behind as it is not blendable. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like [this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/tag/grid/) post

Comment: neat, XAML looks much cleaner looking like this: `local:GridUtils.RowDefinitions="Auto,,,,,,2*"`

Comment: yeah, that blog rocks to be honest